# Creating Multiple GitHub Pull Requests From a Fork

Tags: git, github, pull-request

1. I forked the [ASP.NET MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) project to [RehanSaeed/Mvc](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Mvc).
2. I checked in three distinct change sets into the default dev branch of my fork.
3. I then created [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/pull/2810) Pull Request. However, all three of my changes were automatically added to it.

I have been asked to split my Pull Request into three and make a few additional changes to the code. How do I achieve this? I can see no way to create multiple pull requests. Do I need to create a new branch for each pull request? Also, how do I clean up the mess I've already made? I have a lot of documentation covering how to create a single pull request but none for more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes create a new branch for each feature you add. It's good practice anyways as it allows you to work of different things simultaneously if you so choose. You can use a combination of `git reset` and `git rebase -i` to correct the changes. Possibly you might want to just reset back to the fork commit and then start over adding files on different branches and committing accordingly. The tricky part comes if you edited the same file where you are going to need to split up your work.

Comment: What about the Pull Request I've already raised. Presumably, I should just close it?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed That would seem the logical thing to do. I'm no expert on ASP.NET MVC's workflow though.